# 12v led flickering when DC motor start

Tags: led, dc-motor, led-strip

I have a 12v car battery, 12v led strip and a 12v 775 DC motor.
When I connect the led strip to the battery the strip shines like a star, but when I connect the dc motor, the strip start to flicker and the luminance goes down alot.
The dc motor came with a circuit of tow conductors (I think) and tow 104 capacitors but it's damaged so I took it off.
How to stop the flickering?

Comment: what is tow conductor? ... what is 775 motor?

Comment: measure the voltage across the battery terminals when the motor is running ... connect the LED strip directly to the battery

Comment: Are the LED strip and the motor connected in parallel ? Does the motor spin freely / smoothly when the LEDs are flickering ? Check the voltage at the output of the battery (LED is flickering) if you have a measuring instrument.

Comment: Ah, I am a huge fan of the huge guy 775: (1) 775 Motor Spec - SomanyTech
https://somanytech.com/what-is-775-motor/

(2) AliExpress 775 Motor Catalog
https://www.aliexpress.com/popular/775-motor.html. / to continue, ...

Comment: I say 775 is huge, because though the no load/free run  current might be less than 2A under heavy load the current can be as huge as to 50A!. (3) VEX Robotics Motor Data - Banebots RS-775 18V
https://motors.vex.com/other-motors/bb-775

(4) Motor Handbook - Infineon 2019
https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-motorcontrol_handbook-AdditionalTechnicalInformation-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4626bb628d7016be6a9aa637e69. /to continue, ...

Comment: I am not familiar with "tow conductor", I guess it is the conducting wires used by tow trucks. The 104 capacitor is a typical bypass capacitor to "by pass" or filter high frequency noise/spikes from the motor commutator: Motor Commutator - Wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_(electric), or noises created when switching on/on the motor.

Comment: It is not clear if your circuit is related to Arduino or Raspberry Pi. You might like to give us the link to the circuit. If possible you might like to use another small size 12V battery , or Lipo power bank for the Arduino/Rpi control circuit (even with optical isolation to reduce flickering of the LED strip). In other words, the big 12V card battery for the big motor, another small 12/9/6/6V battery for Arduino/Rpi.